# I have a cross-domain request problem about React

Tags: reactjs, koa2, http-proxy-middleware

I have a problem. When I click the button, an error is reported on the page.

> "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/hello' from origin
> 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource."

Here is client code

```
    function SendRequest() {
        axios({
            url: "http://localhost:8000/hello",
            method: "GET",
        }).then((res)=>
        {
            console.log(res);
        });
    }
```

Here is server code

```
     app.use((ctx, next) => {
        console.log("ASDFSFDSF");
        createProxyMiddleware({
            target: "http://localhost:8000",
            changeOrigin: true
        })
    });
```

The server use koa framework

Answer (score 1):

If you're using express as a backend framework you can install a CORS-Middleware (`npm i cors` in your backend directory) and use it as an active middleware (globally, so for every incoming request) by calling `app.use(cors())` after importing it using `const cors = require("cors")`.

See [here](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) for more information about express and CORS Middleware.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a React problem. That's the back-end blocking the request to your app. Read more about CORS.